# How to arrange pictures randomly in a table with tkinter?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I have to make a memory puzzle in a cours. I have a list with all pictures in it. My problem is how can I arrange these pictures in a table randomly.

```
from tkinter import*
...
```

Please help me with this, how can I arrange pictures in a table randomly.

Comment: Ok I made at table with grid geometry manager andI saved some pictures in a List. My problem Is I don't now how can I arrange these pictures in the table randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `random` module to to come up with random numbers and then use those to position the images. Also, store the numbers your do use in a list so that you can check if it has been used already or not.

```
import random

ref = []

for image in images:
    n = random.randint(0, 3), random.randint(0, 3)
    while n not in ref:
        n = random.randint(0, 3), random.randint(0, 3)
    ref.append(n)
    image.grid(row=n[0], column=n[1])
```

(NOTE: This is just general form code. You will need to adapt it to suit your needs)
Good luck.

Comment: Than you for answering, but I'm a beginner in Python and I couldn't understand your code :( what is the difference between image, images, and what does ref to do ?

Comment: For a beginner, I recommend not using tkinter, or classes at all for that matter, because both of those things are a bit advanced. Like I said, this code is just general, and you will need to change it up to suit your needs. Look into `for` loops and find out what they are and how they work. Then you will understand this code. `images` is just a list with all your images in it. `ref` is a reference of all the places we have already used so that the images do not overlap when when we grid them.

Comment: @The_IT: Thank you for your clarifying, now I understand what is the difference between Images and Image, and what is ref.
I am a student in a course and I have to use Class and Tkinter.

Comment: Ah I see. I find it interesting how they decided to teach you like that. Good luck with that.

Comment: Thank you The_IT. 
Finally I have learned how to arrange pictures randomly.  I used for-loop and a list to save all pictures randomly in it, and then put them in a table :)

Comment: Do they overlap? If not, that's great

Comment: No they don't overlap:). Also  every picture will appear twice in two different place :)